# Loss-value of normal equation vs gradient descent

Tags: python, gradient-descent, normal-equation

My question is if gradient descent can give a better aproximation than normal equation in Python?

for the Loss function, I wrote

```
import numpy as np
def loss(w, X, y):

    X = np.concatenate([np.ones(shape=(len(X),1)),X], axis = 1)
    dif_y = y - X@w
    lossValue = np.mean(dif_y**2)
    return lossValue
```

and for gradient descent (grad_desc) and normal equation (solv)

```
def grad_desc(w,X,y, alpha = 0.01, maxiter = 1000, eps = 1e-2):

    count = 0

    while  loss(w,X,y) >= eps and count <= maxiter:

        w = w - alpha*grad(w,X,y)
        count += 1
    return w

def solv (X,y):
    X = np.concatenate([np.ones((len(X),1)),X], axis = 1)
    s = np.linalg.inv(X.T @ X) @ X.T @y
    return s
```

where my outputs for

```
alpha = 0.000000001
gradDescent = grad_desc(w, Z, y, alpha, 10000)
normalEq = solv(Z,y)


print(loss(gradDescent,Z,y))
```

> 822.5912253816151

```
print(loss(normalEq,Z,y))
```

> 10674.419453701901

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [normal equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares#Objective_function) do not approximate a solution, they are closed form. Thus, the result is the single best estimate of the parameters.

Gradient descent will never find a better estimate of the parameters than the normal equations (assuming the normal equation method is applicable).

That result is idiosyncratic to your implementation.

Comment: Thanks. I took the norm of the gradient of both cases and you are right.

Comment: Also I want to ask you of your opinion about if Is it worthly the gradient descent for linear problema, because with the use of normal equation or precision matrix, it's much faster for the small data frame. I also searched about SVD and how it's more stable in terms of calculation for solving linear systems.